# jq - parsing& replacement based on key-value pairs within json

Tags: json, dictionary, jq

I have a json file in the form of a key-value map. For example:

```
{
    "users":[
    {
        "key1":"user1",
        "key2":"user2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have another json file. The values in the second file has to be replaced based on the keys in first file.

For example 2nd file is:

```
{
    "info":
    {
    "users":["key1","key2","key3","key4"]
    }
}
```

This second file should be replaced with

```
{
    "info":
    {
    "users":["user1","user2","key3","key4"]
    }
}
```

Because the value of key1 in first file is user1. this could be done with any python program, but I am learning jq and would like to try if it is possible with jq itself. I tried different combinations with reading file using slurpfile, then select & walk etc. But couldn't arrive at the required solution.

Any suggestions for the same will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since .users[0] is a JSON dictionary, it would make sense to use it as such (e.g. for efficiency):

Invocation:
    jq -c --slurpfile users users.json -f program.jq input.json

program.jq:

```
$users[0].users[0] as $dict
| .info.users |= map($dict[.] // .)
```

Output:

```
{"info":{"users":["user1","user2","key3","key4"]}}
```

Note: the above assumes that the dictionary contains no null or false values, or rather that any such values in the dictionary should be ignored. This avoids the double lookup that would otherwise be required. If this assumption is invalid, then a solution using `has` or `in` (e.g. as provided by RomanPerekhrest) would be appropriate.

#### Solution to supplemental problem

(See "comments".)

```
$users[0].users[0] as $dict
| second
| .info.users |= (map($dict[.] | select(. != null)))
```

#### sponge

It is highly inadvisable to use redirection to overwrite an input file.
If you have or can install `sponge`, then it would be far better to use it.  For further details, see e.g. "What is jq's equivalent of sed -i?"  in the jq [FAQ](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ).

Comment: A quick followup question, would it be possible to remove or filter out the unchanged keys within this single query. For eg: the result users are only user1 and user2, thus removing key1 and key2 because they were unchanged ?

Comment: Please clarify.

Comment: For example, for the same two input files, is it possible to have the output like:
{"info":{"users":["user1","user2"]} - based on the reason that, these where the only values present in the dictionary file(i.e. the map-file users.json).

Answer (score 1):

**`jq`** solution:

```
jq --slurpfile users 1st.json '$users[0].users[0] as $users 
     | .info.users |= map(if in($users) then $users[.] else . end)' 2nd.json
```

The output:

```
{
  "info": {
    "users": [
      "user1",
      "user2",
      "key3",
      "key4"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks !, it works. To store result back to 2nd.json, I used > 2nd.json